# Manage View of a Table Row at runtime

Tags: android, view, android-widget, tablelayout, tablerow

In my application i am creating and displaying a table at runtime. The table is developed in an Activity class. Everything working fine, only issue is the view of the table. There are four textviews in a row in the table. they are shown adjacently without seperation. How could i make a proper view with a definite space between textviews.

```
            text1.setText("24/02/2011"); //TextView text
            text2.setText("Andy");       //TextView text
            text3.setText("3");          //TextView text
            text4.setText("Repeat");     //TextView text
            tableRow.addView(text1);     //TableRow tableRow
            tableRow.addView(text2);     //TableRow tableRow
            tableRow.addView(text3);     //TableRow tableRow
            tableRow.addView(text4);     //TableRow tableRow
            dueTL.addView(tableRow);     //TableLayout dueTL
```

It display the data like : 24/02/2011Andy3Repeat

Answer (score 1):

You can add `weight` to each `TextView`, also be sure that your `TableView` has `fill_parent` in its width. Also check the `padding` and `margins` of the `TextView`s

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason setting weights doesn't work for your situation, take a look at padding, paddingBottom, paddingLeft, paddingRight, and paddingTop in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

You could either manually add a space to the strings in "setText" or you could set a right margin, if the surrounding ViewGroup supports it, on the TextViews either in XML (`layout_marginRight`) or via Code (`LayoutParams`).